# how to query mysql on the current week?

Tags: mysql, sql

**This is my query for the current day:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog_posts WHERE postStatus = "pending" AND DATE(date_accepted) = CURDATE()
```

now how about if I want to query for this week? Thanks in advance..

Comment: use NOW() function of date.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`YEARWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) function

```
WHERE YEARWEEK(date_accepted) = YEARWEEK(NOW())
```

Don't just use `WEEK()` because that will match weeks from different years.